# How to use electron-dl

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to get the package [electron-dl](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl) working. For that, i use the standard [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) example project.

Unfortunately, applying the example code from electron-dl to the electon-quick-start example does not work for me, meaning nothing is happening and no errors in the browser-console or the terminal.

This is how i implemented the minimal example:

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const {download} = require('electron-dl');

let mainWindow

ipcMain.on('download-item', async (event, {url}) => {
  event.sender.send('download-success', url)
  console.log(url)
  const win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
  console.log(await download(win, url));
});
// ...
```

***renderer.js***

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

$('#btn-dl').click(() => {
    const newURL = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"
    ipcRenderer.send('download-item', {url: newURL}) 
})

ipcRenderer.on('download-success', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
})
```

**index.html**

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<button id="btn-dl">Download</button>

<script>
// jQuery
$ = require('jquery')
// You can also require other files to run in this process
require('./renderer.js')
</script>
```

In this implementation i am simply trying to download the file `5MB.zip` when pressing the Download button.

What am i doing wrong?

Could someone please provide a simple working example of the implenentation of electron-dl using the electron-quick-start example?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it logging download url in your main.js?

Comment: No, the `console.log(url)` is not displaying anything

Comment: Is control going to `btn-dl` click handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having recreated exactly what you described, it works flawlessly for me.

The following is output on the console:

```
http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip
DownloadItem {
  _events: { updated: [Function], done: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2 }
```

The package determines the [location to store the file](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl#directory) itself, if you don't specify it. You can output the path it chooses by default using `app.getPath('downloads')`. For me, this is my home directory (Linux).

If you want to set the download directory yourself:

```js
download(win, url, {
    directory: "/path/to/my/directory/"
})
```

The package will create directories as needed.

Comment: This is crazy, i restarted my computer and it worked. I guess there must have been something wrong with the reload function.